# VUE b-editable-table data model is returning old value upon editing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

I am very new to the VUE framework. The b-editable-table model is not returning the current value but the old value.

Here's the bootstrap code.

```
<b-editable-table disableDefaultEdit
                  :rowUpdate="rowUpdate"
                  :editMode="'row'"
                  bordered
                  class="editable-table"
                  v-model="items"
                  :fields="fields"
                  striped>
    <template #cell(edit)="data">
        <div v-if="data.isEdit">
            <BIconX class="edit-icon" @click="handleSubmit(data, false)"></BIconX>
            <BIconCheck class="edit-icon"
                        @click="handleSubmit(data, true)"></BIconCheck>
        </div>
        <BIconPencil v-else
                     class="edit-icon"
                     @click="handleEdit(data, true)"></BIconPencil>
    </template>
    <template #cell(delete)="data">
        <BIconTrash class="remove-icon"
                    @click="handleDelete(data)"></BIconTrash>
    </template>
</b-editable-table>
```

> **Here's the Javascript Method handleSubmit:**

[image]

The current value of the productPrice 11.63 but when I console data.item.productPrice, it returns me 11.25 which is an old value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of console.log showing objects as 'live' data vs individual data properties that will log their value at the time of the actual console.log statement.  This is further explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects) for console.log.

> Don't use console.log(obj), use console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))).
>
> This way you are sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change. This may not be what you want.

Technically your first console.log should be showing the old productPrice value for some (extremely) short amount of time, same as your other console logs, but then the log **updates** itself to show the new value almost instantaneously.

#### To get the updated value of a table cell

Because of the way b-editable-table is designed, we can't get the updated cell value from an event handler on a cell v-slot *that isn't the cell being updated*. One way to do what you want is to listen to the `input-change` event emitted from the table itself.  This passes a `data` variable that contains the updated values of whatever row was just updated. From this you can assign the updated row data to a new `data` property on your component.  This property will have the information you need when a user clicks the icon in your `#cell(edit)` slot

```html
<b-editable-table
  bordered
  class="editable-table"
  v-model="items"
  :fields="fields"
  @input-change="handleInput"
>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      fields: [ ... ],
      items: [ ... ],
      updatedRow: {} // <-- new property to hold updated row data
},
methods: {
  handleInput(data) {
      if (Object.keys(this.updatedRow).length === 0) {
        this.updatedRow = {
          ...this.items[data.index],
          [data.field.key]: data.value,
        };
      } else {
        this.updatedRow = { ...this.updatedRow, [data.field.key]: data.value };
      }
    },
  // method called by `#cell(edit)` slot
  handleSubmit(data, update) {
      this.rowUpdate = {
        edit: false,
        id: data.id,
        action: update ? "update" : "cancel",
      };
      console.log("this.updatedRow.productPrice", this.updatedRow.productPrice);  // <-- shows latest productPrice
      this.updatedRow = {}
    },
}
```

##### An explanation for:

`this.updatedRow = {...this.items[data.index], [data.field.key]: data.value};`

This line exists because the `data` object passed in by the event contains only pieces of the updated value that we still must manually construct into a row object.  This is the format of the passed in `data` object (unimportant properties removed):

```js
{
  index: 0
  field: {
    key: "productPrice"
    label: "Product Price"
     ...
  }
  value: "11.63"
  ...
}
```

So we have these properties:

1. `index` (the row updated)
2. `field.key` (the cell updated)
3. `value` (the new cell value)

At this point, we still have nothing giving us the full updated row object.
Our v-model `this.items` is still not updated! We have to construct this updated row object ourselves. The code that does this uses [object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

`{ ...this.items[data.index] }` gives us all the current (**old**) key-values of `this.items[row]`

adding `[data.field.key]: data.value` as another property will update the relevant key-value pair that was just updated by the user.

together, `this.updatedRow = {...this.items[data.index], [data.field.key]: data.value};` gives us the row from `this.items` but with the absolute latest values from the row that was just updated by the user.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is not about the console. I just showed that as an example. But when I receive this data, I need to update that data in the database using Web APIs. My main issue is that the data I am passing to the API is not the current value.

Comment: indeed, since we know from console.log that the data is not the updated row data you'll need to go about it a different way.  I've updated my answer with a possible work-around.

Comment: That's great, thanks!
Very well explained.
However, I couldn't understand the following line.
this.updatedRow = {...this.items[data.index], [data.field.key]: data.value};

Comment: Sure thing, it's much easier if I just update my answer again so I can easily paste more code snippets. Check out my latest edit.

Comment: The solution seems very solid. Thanks for the explanation. If I change the product name and the product price, it only updates the last changed value which is the product price.

Comment: Check this out here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjLmz.png

Comment: Hm, ok.  So `updatedRow` is only keeping track of the last change given.  How about we instead update `updatedRow` with it's own values instead of the values of `this.items` for any time `updatedRow` is not initially empty.  We can reset `updatedRow` to be empty object when we're done with it in the `handleSubmit` function.  answer updated!

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked like charm! Appreciate your help! You saved me days of struggle.